# How to troubleshoot TransformedField functionality in Mathematica?

Tags: coordinate-transformation

I list up this method to transform a complex function to Cartestian form, which can be used on virtually any function:

such as:

```
u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -5, 5}];

TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian",  u0[r, phi], {r, phi} -> {x, y}]
```

which yields:

```
  u0[x_, y_] := 
 BesselJ[0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 
  1/(x^2 + y^2)^(5/2)
    2 (-I x (x^2 + y^2)^2 BesselJ[1, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 
      Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] (-x^4 + y^4) BesselJ[2, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 
      I x^5 BesselJ[3, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] - 
      2 I x^3 y^2 BesselJ[3, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] - 
      3 I x y^4 BesselJ[3, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 
      x^4 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] BesselJ[4, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] - 
      6 x^2 y^2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] BesselJ[4, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 
      y^4 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] BesselJ[4, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] - 
      I x^5 BesselJ[5, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 
      10 I x^3 y^2 BesselJ[5, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] - 
      5 I x y^4 BesselJ[5, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]])
```

or

a Hankel and Bessel function together:

```
u[r_, phi_] :=  Piecewise[{{BesselJ[1.5 r, 5]*Exp[I 5 phi], 
0 < r < 1/2}, {(BesselJ[3 r, 5] + BesselY[3 r, 5])*Exp[I 5 phi], 
1/2 < r < 1}, {HankelH1[r, 5]*Exp[I 5 phi], r > 1}}]
```

which yields:

[image: Hankel+Bessel]

which yields the respective given plots, when plotted:

[image: Plot_Bessel_Cartesian]

and

[image: Plot_Hankel+Bessel_Cartesian]

However, my supervisor thinks these plots look "strange". And when you look at the radial plot of the first function, they are not really related.

[image: Radial_form_Bessel]

How can I verify that the TransformedField command did the right job - for such extended functions?

In other words, how to  trobleshoot TransformedField for complex long functions? Is there an analogous command or approach to double-check?

Comment: It should work: `u0[r_, phi_] := g[r (Cos[phi] + I Sin[phi])];
FullSimplify@
 TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
  u0[r, phi], {r, phi} -> {x, y}]` gives result `g[x + I Y]` .

Comment: Can this simplified model represent any case, such as the complex cases and series?